# Aligning a multiline li in an ul

Tags: html, css

I have two li (points) on this page http://animactions.ca/Animactions/le_developpement_des_equipes_de_travail.php that take up two lines. I'm not sure how to properly align them so that they line up with the first line.

I'm referring to this point:

```
Renforcir la cohésion et l’esprit d’équipe pour un travail proactif et durable qui génère des
    rendements supérieurs.
```

Comment: Link is dead, making your question unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your list style so that the list bullets are outside the list.  This is actually the default.

```
.list_a {
   color:#3E3E3E;
   font-family:Calibri;
   font-size:medium;
   list-style:square outside url("Images/list.png");   // not inside
   margin-top:1px;
}
```

Setting the list bullets to "inside" means that they become part of the line items, and thus take up the same layout space as the text of the item.  This causes text to wrap underneath the bullets, rather than occupying a separate layout block.

Comment: How can I then reindent all the bullets (shift them right)

Comment: You can shift the whole list to the right by adding more to your left margin.  Change margin-left to 30 or 40 pixels on your list and it will get underneath your "Les buts!" header.